# Where can I get TFS SDK?

Tags: tfs, sdk, tfs-sdk

I use VS2013.

I'm finding Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll and The GitHttpClient resides in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll . I can not find them from GAC.

I think that they may be in TFS SDK. But I can only find "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Software Development Kit for Java" :http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616.

Where can I get TFS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll** per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) :

> You can find the assemblies in the client object model in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE under ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0, ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5, and PrivateAssemblies.

I found that assembly in the PrivateAssemblies directory.

Regarding **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll** per same page on MSDN:

> You can find the assemblies in the server object model in Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12 under Tools and Application Tier\Web Services\bin.

That assembly is located in the bin folder of the Team Foundation Server. I also found that assembly in my GAC (although I'm not sure when it was installed).

Comment: I can't find the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll under those paths...any ideas where I could find them or what I would need to install?

Answer (score 3):

We now have NuGet packages for the .NET client libraries: [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Online (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet)

For the current Java SDK, it's part of the download for [Team Explorer Everywhere 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727).

Comment: From a NuGet package manager install it by: PM> Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

Answer (score 1):

If you install Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer, you will get the desired files.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Comment: After installed "Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 ", I still cannot find "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll" or "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll".

Comment: Sadly, that link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version now appears to be available at https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/tag/14.135.0.